# REST API problems with PUT/PATCH/DELETE and HTTP headers

Tags: rest, http-headers, http-method, x-http-method-override

I know, that some web-clients can't use PUT/PATCH/DELETE http methods.
I heard about clients, which uses Flash, and about simple http forms.

1. Have you had such problems? With which web-frameworks on client side?
2. Should I expect some problems with custom http headers, which some clients will not be able to send? (e.g. X-HTTP-METHOD-Override)

Comment: Why do you ask? This is a very broad question and there doesn't seem to be any explanation about the situation. Are you having issues with something? Theoretical question? Building an API? Consumer of an API?

Comment: I build rest api, but there is some opinions, that RPC-like, command-oriented api is better and more generic, if you don't work with some real resources(e.g. like work with files on filesystem). 
One of the main arguments is also that some customers can't send PUT/PATCH/DELETE http methods. In this case, a customer can use X-HTTP-METHOD-Override header, and I can route it to proper endpoint. If web-client can't send custom headers - I have a new problem. 
I trying to realize, does it makes sense to change rest api to command-oriented api.

Answer (score 0):

All these three methods are not commonly used and by default

- GET
- POST
- QUERY

  are three methods that are allowed so if you want to use
- PUT
- PATCH
- DELETE

You will have to configure them in your webserver to allow these methods which depends on framework and server configuration in which your application is running

Comment: QUERY isn't a standard nor commonly used verb in HTTP. Neither are PUT etc disallowed by any way in general.